# Extracting column names into contents of one column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
Patient Gene1 Gene2 Gene3 Gene4
patienta 1 0 0 1
patientb 0 1 0 0
patientc 0 1 1 1
```

I want to extract the column names having 1 values against each row and my output should look like

```
Patient Gene
patienta Gene1 
patienta Gene4
patientb Gene2
patientc Gene2
patientc Gene3
patientc Gene4
```

perhaps with list or lapply finction?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will work for you:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df <-read.table(header =TRUE, text="Patient Gene1 Gene2 Gene3 Gene4
patienta 1 0 0 1
patientb 0 1 0 0
patientc 0 1 1 1")

pivot_longer(df, -"Patient", values_to="value", names_to = "Gene") %>% filter(value !=0)


 Patient  Gene  value
  <chr>    <chr> <int>
1 patienta Gene1     1
2 patienta Gene4     1
3 patientb Gene2     1
4 patientc Gene2     1
5 patientc Gene3     1
6 patientc Gene4     1
```